# SQL query return all from a table if X but not Y

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have a SQL table which consists of order details.

**Table Example**

```
order_id | item_type | stock_code | price_code
----------------------------------------------
1        | S         | 0005-01    | NULL
1        | P         | NULL       | PRC-1
1        | S         | 0004       | NULL
2        | S         | 0005-02    | NULL
2        | S         | 0004       | NULL
```

I'm trying to return all order_id's where an order contains a stock code beginning with 0005 but not with a price code beginning with PRC

**My attempt**

```
SELECT order_id
FROM order_detail as ordDetail
WHERE EXISTS(
  SELECT * 
  FROM order_detail as ordDetail2
  WHERE ordDetail2.order_id = ordDetail.order_id
  AND stock_code LIKE '0005-%'
  AND price_code NOT LIKE 'PRC%'
)
```

For some reason, it seems to be ignoring the price_code NOT LIKE argument?

**Expected results**

```
order_id
--------
2
2
```

> I'd love the order_id's to be unique too if that were possible :/

Comment: To explain why what you have isn't working, `{expr} LIKE NULL` will return "unknown", as will `{expr} NOT LIKE NULL`. As "Unknown" is not "True" a clause that needs to evaluate to "True" therefore, effectively, might as well be "False". Nothing is (not) like or (not) equal to `NULL`; including `NULL`. The only way to perform comparisons against a  `NULL` is by using `IS (NOT) NULL`.

Comment: is the table **order_detail** the same as **ORD_DETAIL** ? This seems like a typo that they are not the same table. It also seems the answer from @GordonLinoff doesn't give the exact result you are requesting. His answer only returns 1 row

Comment: @t-clausen.dk thank you, I updated the typo. When testing GordonLinoff 's answer it worked and made sense when reading.

Comment: @Dev.Wol you are requesting 2 rows as result. Please test the links in my answer

Comment: with your new edit, you should pick the answer from @GMB this will return unique order ids. There is no guarantee Gordons answer will return unique order ids

Comment: It wasn't a new edit, I simply highlighted the last sentence as you missed it first time round.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

We can build on your attempt:

```
SELECT od.order_id
FROM order_detail od
WHERE od.stock_code LIKE '0005-%' AND
      NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1
                  FROM ORD_DETAIL od2
                  WHERE od2.order_id = od.order_id AND
                        od2.price_code LIKE 'PRC%'
                 );
```

The particular changes are:

- The condition on `stock_code` is in the outer query not the subquery.
- The condition for price code is `NOT EXISTS` rather than `EXISTS` -- the order should not have such a row.
- The condition in the subquery is `LIKE` not `NOT LIKE`.

Comment: Thank you, this seemed the most logical to read for me and now I've read and understood it makes complete sense why mine wasn't working. Thank you again.

Answer (score 3):

You could use aggregation and a `having` clause with conditional expressions:

```
select order_id
from order_detail
group by order_id
having 
    max(case when stock_code like '0005-%' then 1 end) = 1
    and max(case when price_code like 'PRC%' then 1 end) is null
```

This will give you all (unique) `id`s for which (at least) a record exists where `stock_code = '0005'` and no record exists where `price_code` starts with `'PRC'`.

Answer (score 0):

You need to check for `NULL` values on `price_code`, as Larnu pointed out.

Just replace

```
AND price_code NOT LIKE 'PRC%'
```

for

```
AND (price_code NOT LIKE 'PRC%' OR price_code IS NULL)
```

You can see in the following example how the `NULL` doesn't match against a `LIKE` pattern.

```
SELECT 'Yes!' WHERE 'PRC-1' LIKE 'PRC%'

SELECT 'No T.T!' WHERE NULL LIKE 'PRC%' -- No match
```

Answer (score -2):

Just Try the below, It works .

SELECT DISTINCT order_id
FROM order_detail
WHERE stock_code LIKE '0005-%' AND price_code NOT LIKE 'PRC%'

Comment: Same comment as the other answer: As I mention in the comment above, `AND [ price_code] NOT LIKE 'prc%'` will resolve to `AND NULL NOT LIKE 'prc%'`for some rows; which will **not** evaluate to true, and so those rows will not be included in the result set.